# iOS DatePicker not setting initial value

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, uidatepicker

I am using storyboards and I have an outlet for the datePicker and I set the date like this in code

```
let date = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(-48 * 3600) //meaning 2 days ago the date
datePicker.setDate(date, animated: false)
```

But when I run the app it always shows the current date

Answer (score 0):

[image: Storyboard property]

After changing the "Date" property on the storyboard to "Custom" I could set the date on code as I showed above